# mergeForm() - symfony

Tags: symfony1

I'm using mergeForm to display a form and then another merged into it.

The form I'm editting is the admin module for Article with a ContentItemForm merged.

Schema in simple terms is:

```
Article
id

ContentItem
id
article_id
is_comment
```

In my ArticleForm I have the following:

```
  public function configure()
  {
     $this->mergeForm(new ContentItemForm(ContentItemPeer::retrieveByPK($this->getObject()->getId())));
  }

  public function save($con = null)
  {
    parent::save();

    $this->updateContentItem();

    return $this->object;
  }

  protected function updateContentItem()
  {
    // update content item
    if (!is_null($article_content = $this->getContentItem())) 
    {

     $values = $this->getValues();
     if ( $article_content->isNew() ) 
     {
         $values['article_id'] = $this->object->getId();
     }

      $article_content->fromArray($values, BasePeer::TYPE_FIELDNAME);

      $article_content->save();
    }
   }

   protected function getContentItem()
   {
      if (!$this->object->getContentItem()) 
      {
        return new ContentItem();
      }
      else
      {
      return $this->object->getContentItem();
      }
   }
```

In the admin, this merges the form and i see the contentItemForm and it's fields.
is_comment is a boolean value and therefore displays a checkbox.
When I have it checked, it is suppoed to update the is_comment field in the content_item table to 1, unchecked and saved, should be 0.

Unfortunately, this isn't working. The is_comment field is never updated.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set a relation between Article and ContentItem? Then you shouldn't have to do anything specific in the save() method.

Comment: I am using Propel 1.4 and I do not think relations are possible

Comment: But that is that only using sfPropel15Plugin? I don't see anywhere on that link mentioning relations in the yaml schema